# How to enable AdobeStock integration?

Tags: magento2, admin, cms, adobe-stock

I have a Magento 2.3.4 installed and I installed the AdobeStock integration via the official repository.

https://github.com/magento/adobe-stock-integration

How could I enable it via the admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable it providing your key.

## Admin panel

1. Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System Tab.
2. Now Click on **Adobe stock Integration Section**,
3. Enable Adobe Stock to **Yes**.
4. Add **API Key** (Client ID) and Client Secret text field value from the Adobe Integration.
5. Save Config to save changes.

[image: Magento 2 Adobe Stock]

Reference [here](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/enable-adobe-stock-integration-magento-2/).